# iOS removeFromSuperview and zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c

I add multiple images and show them with zoom. 
Due to limited memory size, I should try to remove some of them which has already seen with removeFromSuperview. 
My problem is that when I try to zoom, selected image is disappeared by removeFromSuperview.

My codes are as below:

```
if ( [contentView viewWithTag:CONTENT_IMAGE_TAG_NUM + index] ) {
    if (index > 2) {
        UIView *prevContentView = [contentView viewWithTag:(CONTENT_IMAGE_TAG_NUM + index - 2)];
        if (prevContentView) {
            [prevContentView removeFromSuperview];
            [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory];
        }
    }
} else {
    UIImageView *imageView = [self addContentImage:index contentArray:contentArray prevImageHeight:prevImageHeight];
-----

}
```

When I try to zoom at 3rd image, it is disappeared. 
To solve zoom problem, I removed 'removeFromSuperview' and could zoom well. But it made memory problem. I got memory warning. How can I solve this problem? I want to fix both zoom and memory issue. 
Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cells are reused in table views and collection views, so you do not have to bother much about memory since the image view that you use will switch its `image` and therefore release previously retained image. SDImageCache on the other side should flush memory cache when memory warning received. So I guess you have a problem somewhere else.